# Need to run SecureCRT session from the CMD

Tags: python, cmd, secure-crt

Sorry for any issues but this is my first post here and thank you in advance for your any comments.

I need to run following command from the CMD: C:\Users\Name\Documents\CRT\SecureCRT.EXE /S \DEVICES\device where device will be added in the loop from the list.

I got following:

```
for p in devices:
    subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\Name\Documents\CRT\SecureCRT.EXE /S'] + devices)
```

I got follwing error:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Name\Documents\TICKETS\2020\July 2020\Change start stop2.py", line 89, in <module> subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\Name\Documents\CRT\SecureCRT.EXE /S'] + devices) File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__ restore_signals, start_new_session) File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use this
subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\Name\Documents\CRT\SecureCRT.EXE /S'] + devices)

Use // insted of /

Answer (score 0):

This command fix the issue.

```
for p in devices:
subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\Name\Documents\CRT\SecureCRT.EXE', '/T', '/S', '\\DEVICES\\CORE\\' + p])
```